# Trying to read this Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read this code. As far as I can tell, it's checking if the child element is "at position" (but it's equal to a string? That makes no sense to me). If it isn't, then it adds 2 to the offset, if it is, it does nothing.

```
  var p = document.getElementById(parent);
  var c = document.getElementById(child );

  var top  = (c["at_position"] == "y") ? p.offsetHeight+2 : 0;
  var left = (c["at_position"] == "x") ? p.offsetWidth +2 : 0;
```

And then here, this for loop does not make sense to me - why does it start with a semicolon?

```
  for (; p; p = p.offsetParent)
  {
    top  += p.offsetTop;
    left += p.offsetLeft;
  }
```

Can anyone clarify how to read this a little bit better? I'm trying to reduce the distance between the parent and the child to a limited extent (Only for "left")

Comment: It is optional, read the docs [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FStatements#for_Statement)

Answer (score 3):

It loops while `p` is `truethy` that is, `p` is not `null` because `offsetParent` will likely be `null` once your reach the top.

It's equivalent to:

```
var p = document.getElementById(parent);
while (p !== null) {
    top += p.offsetTop;
    left += p.offsetLeft;
    p = p.offsetParent;
}
```

---

Normally a for loop looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
```

the first bit `var i = 0` is the initialization part. You can leave it empty like:

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < array.length; i += 1) {
```

You can also do this:

```
for (var i = 0, j = 10 - i; i < array.length; i += 1, j -= 1) {
```

Although there are perhaps better ways to do it. Just showing you the syntax :)

---

The second part is the part that must be `truethy`, if it's `false` the for loop will stop. This can't be empty of course.

---

The last part is the incrementer part, which can also be empty. So you could have:

```
var p = document.getElementById(parent);
for (; p ;) {
    p = p.offsetParent;
}
```

It looks weird, but works. I wouldn't recommend this though because *it looks weird*, and by that I mean that it looks like a bug.

Comment: +1 for readability in this case. Is the for loop faster than the while loop? Even if so, might not be worth it...the while loop makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @jlbruno It's Javascript. It probably a makes negligible difference which one you use compared to what you do inside the loop, even more so than in C. (These days, if you're trying to do microoptimise code for whichever reason, you should worry more about cache misses and branch prediction than how your compiler implements a language construct.)